# Sending a notification from a service in Android

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have a service running, and would like to send a notification. Too bad, the notification object requires a `Context`, like an `Activity`, and not a `Service`.

Do you know any way to by pass that ? I tried to create an `Activity` for each notification but it seems ugly, and I can't find a way to launch an `Activity` without any `View`.

Comment: Umm... a Service _is_ a context!

Comment: God, I such a dumbbass. Ok, sorry to waste everybody's time.

Comment: That's fine - it's a good Google question.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Both `Activity` and `Service` actually `extend` [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) so you can simply use `this` as your `Context` within your `Service`.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(/* your notification */);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = /* your intent */;
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, /* your content */, pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify(/* id */, notification);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll have a lot of problems doing notification from a service. If you have problems then take a look at this http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e95740e776982f89

Comment: how can you do this using the Notification.Builder? because setLatestEventInfo is already deprecated.

Answer (score 80):

This type of Notification is deprecated as seen from documents:

```
@java.lang.Deprecated
public Notification(int icon, java.lang.CharSequence tickerText, long when) { /* compiled code */ }

public Notification(android.os.Parcel parcel) { /* compiled code */ }

@java.lang.Deprecated
public void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context context, java.lang.CharSequence contentTitle, java.lang.CharSequence contentText, android.app.PendingIntent contentIntent) { /* compiled code */ }
```

**Better way**
You can send a notification like this:

```
// prepare intent which is triggered if the
// notification is selected

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

// build notification
// the addAction re-use the same intent to keep the example short
Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
        .setContentText("Subject")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Call", pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "More", pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "And more", pIntent).build();


NotificationManager notificationManager = 
  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

**Best way**
Code above needs minimum API level 11 (Android 3.0).
If your minimum API level is lower than 11, you should you use [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)'s NotificationCompat class like this.

So if your minimum target API level is 4+ (Android 1.6+) use this:

```
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    -------------
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mylogo)
                    .setContentTitle("My Notification Title")
                    .setContentText("Something interesting happened");
    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;

    Intent targetIntent = new Intent(this, MyFavoriteActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Comment: this should be the best answer since the accepted one is deprecated

Comment: @MarcelKrivek Seems he or she "forgot" to quote their source.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Comment: What is "NotificationReceiver"?

Comment: "NotificationReceiver" is the Activity that will be opened by the Notification. Check the link provided by @StarWind0 .

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder already deprecated. Its now no longer best answer

Answer (score 7):

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public void PushNotification()
{
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,notificationIntent,0);

    //set
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cal_icon);
    builder.setContentText("Contents");
    builder.setContentTitle("title");
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    nm.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(),notification);
}
```

Comment: The topic question is from a SERVICE not Activity

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if my solution is best practice. Using the `NotificationBuilder` my code looks like that:

```
private void showNotification() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    </activity>
```

and here the Service:

```
    <service
        android:name=".services.ProtectionService"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
    </service>
```

I don't know if there really is a `singleTask` at `Service` but this works properly at my application...

Comment: what is the builder in this ?

Answer (score -3):

If none of these work, try `getBaseContext()`, instead of `context` or `this`.

Comment: You should not use `getBaseContext()` is these scenarios.