# How to show notification from background service?

Tags: android, notifications

The project I am working on has two different apps, 1 is server and other is client. Server app has 1 service class, which initiates server thread in `onStartCommand()` function. Class for server thread is defined in service class itself. Whenever server receives any data from client it stores in the database. So problem is, I want to notify user that new data has been arrived through notification or toast message whichever possible. Also tell me where should I write code for notification, whether I should write in service class or thread class or `firstActivity` class from which i am starting server service. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending a notification from a service in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207269/sending-a-notification-from-a-service-in-android)

Comment: @Reno:I already referred this post, but i didn't understand where should i place that code, also that code is incomplete. I am beginner in Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I reading this incorrectly? Both your server app and your client app are both on the same Android device?

In any case, take a look at the ApiDemos for code for notifications through a service.

And since you're probably going to be dealing with a remote server (and not a local one) and all the latency issues associated with the network, I think you better wrap your service in an AsyncTask.

Also learn about Broadcast Receivers, registered Broadcast Receivers can be great way to trigger Services/Activities without the need to have your own Service polling in a loop indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks! my server and client app r running on different emulators, there is no problem in data transfer and storing it in database. I will look at Broadcast Receivers. Is there any way to detect there is change in database table? So that if changes found i can notify user from activity class.

Comment: As u said , i have used broadcast reciever, and it is working, but i want to send 1 string with broadcast and display that string in toast msg. I have used intent.putextra(). but at the receiver end i am recieving null value, i think problem is in my get extra code, can u plz tell me how to receive data send by broadcast intent.

Answer (score 10):

First you need to read this article on how to use [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Next use this to send a Notification, you can write this code in the service class at the point where you receive some data from the client.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
CharSequence notiText = "Your notification from the service";
long meow = System.currentTimeMillis();

Notification notification = new Notification(icon, notiText, meow);

Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "Your notification";
CharSequence contentText = "Some data has arrived!";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivityThatYouWantToLaunch.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

int SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED = 1;
notificationManager.notify(SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED, notification);
```