# Pass a Context an IntentService

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
Intent publishIntent = new Intent(HistoryDoneVsPlanned.this, MyIntentService.class);
publishIntent.putExtra(HistoryMap.KEY_WORKOUT_ID, workoutId);
```

where HistoryDoneVsPlanned is my current Activity and MyIntetService is a IntentService.

and my goal is pass the current context of the activity at the intentService like this:

```
publishIntent.putExtra("CONTEXT", HistoryDoneVsPlanned.this);
```

but is not possible.

Is a good practice? I need make the Toast and notification into another class (not Activity) and I need the context of the activity.

Comment: The `IntentService` class is a subclass of `Context`, that way you can use `this` where you need a `Context` in your service.

Comment: Why exactly do you need Activity's context in a Service?

Comment: I need Activity context in a Service beacause This service construct the objects and this objects call methods to do toast and notification and toast and notification if I dont understand bad need Activity Context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is a good practice? I need make the Toast and notification into
>   another class (not Activity) and I need the context of the activity.

*No. This is not a good practice. You should show notification from `Services`. But it depends on application behavior you can do also.*

***Case 1:*** If Service/ Intent Service running and doing task into background..

*You should show notification instead of Toast. Read* [How to show notification from background service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701942/how-to-show-notification-from-background-service)

***Case 2:*** If Service/ Intent Service running and doing task into background, but returns result to an Activity (Which means User is present for your app)

*You can show Toast in this case. Read* [Show toast at current Activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730675/show-toast-at-current-activity-from-service)

***Note :*** *And do not pass context via `Intent` to `MyIntentService`. You can get `Context` into `MyIntentService` also by doing `MyIntentService.this`. And this is because all Android `Components` overrides `Context` class, on of them is `IntentService`.*

Comment: Sorry but I cant show notification from the service beacause the service call the methods (of a class not Activity) e into the methods I need to call notification. So If I  understand well I do call notification into the class extern at the Service.

Comment: If that method s of another class, then pass Context into parameter of that method. like method would be `yourMethod(Context mContext, otherParms)` and you should call this method from Service as `thatClassObject.yourMethod(MyIntentService.this, otherParams)`. Let me know if you find any confusion about..

Comment: Yes I'm a little confused sorry...I think:
1)pass the context of the service at my class
2)with this context use notification but I dont  knkow if it is correct

Comment: The logic which you were discussing was correct :D. No problem to sen d Context object to a method as param.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the context in `cross-activity` usage, you should not bound the `Activity context` to the action, since then even if the activity is destroyed, it will not be garbage-collected, as it is still referenced from the running task. In those cases, you should use the `Application context`.  For more look at [the android developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

Comment: I dont understand the difference beetwen context and application context.

Comment: take a look at this so# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context

Comment: Read at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context and http://t.co/9R0bPWiKc5 . Last one is very good resource to know about Contexts.