# How to pass context var when I use IntentService in BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

I need to use Context object in the function killCall, but I don't know how to pass the Context object to KillCall, could you help me? Thanks!

```
public class ReceiverCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              Intent msgIntent = new Intent(context, InternetServerCall.class);     
              context.startService(msgIntent);
    }

}


public class InternetServerCall extends IntentService{

    public InternetServerCall(String name) {
        super("InternetServerCall");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {      
        HandleCall.killCall(context); //Need  context
    }

}


public class HandleCall {

    public static boolean killCall(Context context) {
        try {
            ....
           Toast.makeText(context, "PhoneStateReceiver kill incoming call Ok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception ex) { // Many things can go wrong with reflection calls
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `Context` into `InternetServerCall` by doing `InternetServerCall.this`. And this is because all `Android` `Components` overrides `Context` class, on of them is `IntentService`.

You can also use `getApplicationContext()` into `IntentService` to get context. You can read my another similar answer [Pass a Context an IntentService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281900/pass-a-context-an-intentservice).

---

But you can not display `Toast` from `IntentService` directly, because it needs UI thread but `IntentService` runs into background thread.  You need to use `Handler` to show Toast, like below example

```
public class TestService extends IntentService {


    private Handler handler;  

    public TestService(String name) {
        super(name);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public TestService () {
          super("TestService"); 
    }


    @Override 
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  
       handler = new Handler();  
       return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);  
    }  

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         handler.post(new Runnable() {  
                @Override 
                public void run() {        
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Handling Intent..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }  
          });   
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) is subclass of `Context` so you can pass in `this`:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {      
    HandleCall.killCall(this);
}
```