# How to Send Notifications to Server App when a New Entry is Added to the Database

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working with two apps . one is the client app and the other one is the server app . As soon as the client places an order. A new entry is created in the database
I want to send notification to the server app as soon as the customer places an order.

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("requests");
    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"new entry",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG,"I know whats cooking " );
        }
```

this code will be used in background activity to detect a change in the database.
What will be the best practice?
What if we use the realtime firebase triggers the onCreate() method which is triggered whenever a new entry is added to the database . I am unable to understand where should I place this trigger code that I found in [this link](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/07/cloud-functions-realtime-database.html)
I found a similar question but couldn't find the answer.
[How to show notification from background service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701942/how-to-show-notification-from-background-service/49377499?noredirect=1#comment85755645_49377499)

Comment: you can create a REST API on your server and call it every time when a user does a new entry.

Comment: Look into Cloud Functions for Firebase to write backend code that triggers in response to changes in your database.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: In your onChildAdded call a web api using volley or retrofit whatever you want and send data with it to server app

Comment: @DougStevenson I didn't exactly understand where should I be placing the code

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to do exactly that. What you should do is register a `onCreate` function to your database reference. This function gets triggered only when a new child is created to your database reference. Then use [FCM push notification API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to send your notification.

Comment: I have mentioned a code above , according to this code , a toast must be displayed every time there is a new data base entry but the toast doesn't appear