# Token not null for an application in alert builder

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using a receiver to make an alertbox every week. However i get following error with the code below

> Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

The code I am using is

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {
           try {
                 displayAlert("Have you seen your chiropractor this month?", "Alert!", context);
                } 
           catch (Exception e) 
            {
               Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
        }



         public void displayAlert(final String error, String title, final Context context)
         {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context.getApplicationContext()).setMessage(error)  
                .setTitle(title)  
                .setCancelable(true)  
                .setNeutralButton("Continue",  
                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                           dialog.cancel();
                            Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, Appointment.class);
                            context.startActivity(newIntent);
                   }  
                   })  
                .show(); 
            }
    }
```

Comment: _However i get following error with the code below_ what error you are getting?

Comment: @PradeepSimha the First line check it out, Unable to add Window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want notifications, I just did a cheap trick

I have created a blank activity MYExtraActivity and called it in Receiver

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, MYExtraActivity .class);
                            context.startActivity(newIntent);
```

In this new Activity i have defined an alert and everything

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `getApplicationContext()`

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(error)  
            .setTitle(title)  
            .setCancelable(true)  
            .setNeutralButton("Continue",  
               new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                       dialog.cancel();
                        Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, Appointment.class);
                        context.startActivity(newIntent);
               }  
               })  
            .show();
```

in place of `getApplicationContext()` pass `ActivityName.this` or `getContext()`

Comment: can't do any Activity.this, its a broadcastreceiver, i tried with context only but failed

Comment: Try only passing context. i.e. `new AlertDialog.Builder(context)` . And if compiler doesn't accept that convert the context to an Activity

Comment: @MuhammadUmar This should also help http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
context.getApplicationContext();
```

use

```
this
```

And try again, this should work

Comment: "this" is a broadcastReceiver

Comment: @MuhammadUmar, try ActivityName.this

Comment: No enclosing instance of the type MYACTIVITY is accessible in scope

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think that it is a good idea to show an `AlertDialog` from your `BroadcastReceiver`. You should create a `Notification` instead and open some activity when user click it.

Comment: you can find more information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350385/launching-dialog-from-service