# Show alertdialog from service

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need show AlertDialog from service and I'm using code on service:

```
public void onCreate() {
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GroupActivity.class);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert=new Builder(getApplicationContext());
        alert.setTitle("Success!");
        alert.setMessage("Hien tai");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Success", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    };
```

But the code throw execption.
How to do that?

Comment: show the logcat error please

Comment: What exception you got?

Comment: You can not do. Dialog needs Activity context.

Comment: Instead you can show dialog like System alert by adding a `View` to `WindowManager`...

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350385/launching-dialog-from-service and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918571/how-to-display-a-dialog-from-a-service

Comment: I known that Dialog needs Activity context. But I need to do that, how to do it.

Comment: or you can start the `Activity` from a `Service` and use `Dialog.Theme` as `Activity`'s Theme. don't forget to add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when starting Activity from `Service`...

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate() {
    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GroupActivity.class);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Success!")
                .setMessage("Hien tai")
                .setPositiveButton("Success", new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                }).create();

    alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Please note that you have to use the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```