# Use a Handler inside an IntentService started by a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, handler

I want to use an `IntentService` (which is started from a `BroadcastReceiver`) to download a file from Internet, but I want to inform the user if the file was downloaded successfully or not and if was downloaded to parse the file. Using a handler and `handleMessage` inside my `IntentService` is a good solution? From what I read `IntentServices` is simple worker threads that expire after handling the intent, so is it possible that the handler does not handle the message ?

```
private void downloadResource(final String source, final File destination) {
    Thread fileDownload = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(source);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)
                                               url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();

                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength;

                while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                }
                fileOutput.close();

                // parse the downloaded file ?
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                destination.delete();
            }
        }
    });
    fileDownload.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to create a notification to inform the user, then you can do it after download in your IntentService (see [Sending a notification from a service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207269/sending-a-notification-from-a-service-in-android))

If you want to display a more elaborated UI (via an Activity) then you probably want to start one of your app's activities with startActivity() method (see [android start activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service))

If you don't need any UI stuff, just do the parsing in the `IntentService` right after download.

Comment: I simply want to parse the downloaded file, without any UI interaction.

Comment: Oh ok, but you said "I want to inform the user if the file was downloaded successfully or not". If you don't need any UI, why don't you parse it in your IntentService after download ?

Comment: I added some code to the post. so it is ok to parse the file at line "// parse the downloaded file ?" ?

Comment: Sure. Why not? As long as your parsing does modify any UI stuff.

Comment: I'll give it a try in few minutes.

Comment: But I don't see why you manually start a new thread...I assume that the `downloadResource()` method is called from your `IntentService` which already runs in a background thread.