# cancel Service when user clicks Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-notifications

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501225/using-service-to-run-background-and-create-notification) I got a service that does some work in the background. When the service starts, I'm displaying a notification. Usually you can assing an intent to the notification that is triggered when the user clicks onto the notification. Mostly an activity is then started.

But how can I use a notification to inform the background service that the user want's to cancel its operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a BroadcastReceiver to stop the Service, which is triggered through the PendingIntent of the Notification.

Have a look at the [PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and use it instead of the `PendingIntent.getActivity()` method. You can use it like this:

```
  Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(context, YourBroadcastReceiver.class);      
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, broadcastIntent, 0);
  Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
         ...
         .setContent(pendingIntent);
         .build();

  notification.setContent(pendingIntent);
```

The BroadcastReceiver could be an inner class in your Service to simply call `stopService()` in the `onReceive()` method.