# Local notifications not showing when app is closed using recent apps by user.

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-notifications

Hi i am making a habit tracker app and when a new habit is created by user i call `sendNotification()` method for calling notifications at time specified by user.I want to show these notifications everyday at time specified by user.
Now notifications are showing up when app is running or when app is minimized but when i close app (not from settings) notifications are shown.
Here's my code:

```
private void sendNotification(){
    NotificationReceiver.setupAlarm(this, notificationCalendar);
}

public class NotificationReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

public NotificationReceiver() {
}

public static void setupAlarm(Context context, Calendar notificationCalendar) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = getStartPendingIntent(context);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notificationCalendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent  serviceIntent = NotificationIntentService.createIntentStartNotificationService(context);
    startWakefulService(context, serviceIntent);
}

private static PendingIntent getStartPendingIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
}

public class NotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

public NotificationIntentService() {
    super(NotificationIntentService.class.getSimpleName());
}

public static Intent createIntentStartNotificationService(Context context) {
    return new Intent(context, NotificationIntentService.class);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try{
    processStartNotification();
    }finally {
        WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}

private void processStartNotification() {
    // Do something. For example, fetch fresh data from backend to create a rich notification?
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Habit Time")
            .setContentText("Hey time for your habit")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
}
}

//Manifest file
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <receiver android:name=".notification.NotificationReceiver"/>

    <service
        android:name=".notification.NotificationIntentService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

Comment: should i use service for notifications?

Comment: why its not working with broadcast receiver

Comment: your question is confusing so notification is not shown when app is killed...??

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 notifications do not show when app is not in memory i.e i swipe it from button that shows all apps in background

Comment: I want my notifications to work kind of like alarms even if you that app is not in memory it still shows

Answer (score 0):

The notification won't show until you make a background service for them. Create a background service and send broadcast from that service, this service will keep running weather your app is running or not. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501225/using-service-to-run-background-and-create-notification) detailed answer.

Make a NotificationService class and extend it like below.

```
public class NotificationService extends Service{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    /* send your notification from here, in timely manner */
}

  }
```

Start is from your activity like this

```
 Intent i = new Intent("com.example.package.NotificationService");
            startService(i);
```

This code is written to give you an idea. I didn't test it.

Comment: I used that method but notifications only show when app is in memory!!

Comment: where is your Service Class?

Comment: I used that in my code exactly it was written but not working when app is not in background

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code: it creates an alarm for a specific time in a day using alarmanager and repeat it daily...

Declare

```
Calendar cal_alarm;
```

Now set the calender object for specific time to alarm

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy hh:mm a");
String time=""21 12 2016 8:10 AM"
cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
cal_alarm.setTime(dateFormat.parse(time));
```

Set the alarm

```
public void set_alarm() {
    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    long current_time = calNow.getTimeInMillis();
    Log.d("ALARM CALENDER VALUES", cal_alarm.toString());
    long alarm_time_in_millis = cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis();
    //check if time is alreday passed or not
    if (alarm_time_in_millis > current_time) {
        new Alarm_task(getApplicationContext(), cal_alarm).run();
 }

public class Alarm_task implements Runnable {

    // The date selected for the alarm
    private final Calendar cal;
    // The android system alarm manager
    private final AlarmManager am;
    // Your context to retrieve the alarm manager from
    private final Context context;
    long alarm_time2;
    int _id;

    public Alarm_task(Context context, Calendar cal) {
        this.context = context;
        this.am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        this.cal = cal;
        this._id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        alarm_time2 = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), alarm_time2 + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Request to start are service when the alarm date is upon us
        // We don't start an activity as we just want to pop up a notification into the system bar not a full activity
        Intent i = new Intent("com.package_name");
        i.setAction("com.package_name");
        /** Creating a Pending Intent */
        PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), _id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        /** Converting the date and time in to milliseconds elapsed since epoch */
        long alarm_time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        /** Setting an alarm, which invokes the operation at alart_time each day*/
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm_time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, operation);
    }
}
```

Now in manifest define an explicit activity which handle the alarm intent and show popup dialog and notification during alarm time

```
<activity
        android:name=".Prereminder"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
             //same as your alarm task
            <action android:name="com.package_name" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now in your Prereminder.java

```
    public class Prereminder extends FragmentActivity {
    String msg = "Helloo";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
        sendNotification();
        /** Creating an Alert Dialog Window */
        Reminder_alert alert = new Reminder_alert();
        /** Opening the Alert Dialog Window */
        alert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Reminder_alert");
    }


    private void sendNotification() {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //handle notification on click
        Intent myintent = new Intent(this, Home_page.class);
        myintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_small)
                        .setContentTitle("Alarm")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Now your Reminder_alert class show the popup dialog during alarm:

```
    public class Reminder_alert extends DialogFragment {

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /** Turn Screen On and Unlock the keypad when this alert dialog is displayed */
        getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);


        /** Creating a alert dialog builder */
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        /** Setting title for the alert dialog */
        builder.setTitle("ALARM ON");

        /** Setting the content for the alert dialog */
        builder.setMessage("WAKE UP NOW");

        /** Defining an OK button event listener */
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        /** Creating the alert dialog window */
        return builder.create();
    }

    /**
     * The application should be exit, if the user presses the back button
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- in simple way first use this function to create alarm

```
private void createAlarm(Date start_alarm_date, String schedual_type ,String schedule_id){
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushLocalNotification.AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("Your_Action_Name"); //this action you will use later
    intent.putExtra("Extra", any_extra_you_want_add);// remove if you want add extra
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);


    // Set the alarm to start at specific date
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);

    // repeat it "daily":
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

2- create IntentService and make your receiver extend **BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class PushLocalNotification extends IntentService {

private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private String mScheduleID;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public PushLocalNotification() {
    super("pushLocalNotification");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // call create local notification here
}


public static class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("Your_action_Name")) {
            // call service here.
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(context, PushLocalNotification.class);
            sendIntent.putExtra("Extra_name", intent.getStringExtra("Previos_extra_you_add_before"));
            context.startService(sendIntent);
        }
    }
}
private void createNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    //Create Intent to launch this Activity again if the notification is clicked.
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(intent);

    // Sets the ticker text
    builder.setTicker(getResources().getString(R.string.custom_notification));

    // Sets the small icon for the ticker
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_custom);

    // Cancel the notification when clicked
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    // Build the notification
    Notification notification = builder.build();

    // Inflate the notification layout as RemoteViews
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);

    // Set text on a TextView in the RemoteViews programmatically.
    final String time = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date()).toString();
    final String text = getResources().getString(R.string.collapsed, time);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, text);

    /* Workaround: Need to set the content view here directly on the notification.
     * NotificationCompatBuilder contains a bug that prevents this from working on platform
     * versions HoneyComb.
     * See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30495
     */
    notification.contentView = contentView;

    // Add a big content view to the notification if supported.
    // Support for expanded notifications was added in API level 16.
    // (The normal contentView is shown when the notification is collapsed, when expanded the
    // big content view set here is displayed.)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        // Inflate and set the layout for the expanded notification view
        RemoteViews expandedView =
                new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_expanded);
        notification.bigContentView = expandedView;
    }

    // START_INCLUDE(notify)
    // Use the NotificationManager to show the notification
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(0, notification);
}
```

}

3- final step don't forget to declare service and receiver inside manifest file

```
<receiver
        android:name=".PushLocalNotification$AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="Your_Action_name:)" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".PushLocalNotification" />
```

be patient and have fun :)

Comment: Thanks but your code also works only when app is running or in background

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a method which contains your Code where you will define your Time or at what time you want to show the notification.This method need to be called from where you want user to ask for notification.

   ```
   public void getNotification () {

       AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notification_receiver.class);

       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       intent.setData((Uri.parse("custom://"+System.currentTimeMillis())));

       alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
       calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
       calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
       calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
       if (now.after(calendar)) {
           Log.d("Hey","Added a day");
           calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
       }

       alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
   }
   ```
2. Create a `Notification_receiver` class which is going to extend Broadcast Receiver here you are going to define your **Channel Id** as it is perfectly working for **API 25 and above** this the Notification_receiver class:

   ```
   import android.app.Notification;
   import android.app.NotificationChannel;
   import android.app.NotificationManager;
   import android.app.PendingIntent;
   import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
   import android.media.RingtoneManager;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Build;
   import android.util.Log;

   import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

   //Created By Prabhat Dwivedi
   public class Notification_receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
           NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
           PendingIntent pendingIntent;

           if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
               NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("Your App Name",
                       "You app Package Name",
                       NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
               String channel_Id = channel.getId();
               CharSequence channel_name = channel.getName();
               Log.e("Notification_receiver", "channel_Id :" + channel_Id);
               Log.e("channel_name", "channel_name :" + channel_name);

               channel.setDescription("Make entry of today's spending now");
               notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
           }

           builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yourapp_logo)
                   .setChannelId("Your app Name is your Channel Id")
                   .setContentTitle("Your title")
                   .setContentText("Your Description")
                   .setAutoCancel(true);

   //nder this you will find intent it is going to define after clicking notification which activity you want to redirect
           Intent repeatingIntent = new Intent(context, HomePage.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, repeatingIntent,    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
           builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
           notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Kindly also add the Notification receiver inside `AndroidManifest.xml` file

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".Notification_receiver"/>
   ```