# Launch app on background for manage notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications

Hello I have trouble with manage notification

I have app with control weather in some place (when change I want build notification) one a day control it's okay, for example on 10:00 and ecery day, If I can run one methot/activity/class for control weather and launch notification if need..

I have only simple notofication from developer android. 
and I have troubble for find some "advice" with my problem.. i find some with use firebase, but thing so it's not for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a Service (which is basically an Activity without an interface). They have a `Context` and you can send notifications from there.

[Have a look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501225/using-service-to-run-background-and-create-notification)

Comment: I try this https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8jxaowbi6wpot5/NotificationBySchedule.zip?dl=0 from yours answer but I thing not work, I launch app and press start, ok ... and first notofication ok.. I exit app from RAM too and notification not...