# how to show android notification and application icon

Tags: android

I have a service running, and would like to send a notification. Too bad, the notification object requires a context, like an Activity, and not a service.

Do you know any way to by pass that ? I tried to create an Activity for each notification bu it seems ugly, and I can't find a way to launch an Activity without any view.

i also want to sent my application icon to notification to show icon top of screen

Comment: Use `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Even services have contexts. If you don't want to use `getApplicationContext()` you can use `this`

Comment: ok, now how can i send notification and application icon?

Comment: take a look at [this answer][1]

hope that helps.
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207269/sending-a-notification-from-a-service-in-android

Comment: @soheila have you done with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working code , which creates a notification from a service itself. 
hope it will help you,

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {




     //We get a reference to the NotificationManager
       NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       String MyText = "Reminder";
       Notification mNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, MyText, System.currentTimeMillis() );
       //The three parameters are: 1. an icon, 2. a title, 3. time when the notification appears

       String MyNotificationTitle = "Medicine!";
       String MyNotificationText  = "Don't forget to take your medicine!";

       Intent MyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       PendingIntent StartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,MyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
       //A PendingIntent will be fired when the notification is clicked. The FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag cancels the pendingintent

       mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationTitle, MyNotificationText, StartIntent);

       int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
       notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID , mNotification);  
       //We are passing the notification to the NotificationManager with a unique id.

      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return START_STICKY;
   }
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```