# Notification Manager on background process

Tags: android, notifications, rss

I am creating an Android app which is just a WebView for wrapping a news website. In this app I also want a process that parses an RSS feed every eg. 5 minutes. If there is a new post in that RSS then raise notification.

The question is, when the app is not running can the notification still be raised? If it's possible, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a service [(Android Service)](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) which polls the RSS feed checking for new posts.

From the Docs:

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service and it will continue to run in the background even if the user switches to another application.

When a new RSS post is found, use the [Notification Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) to fire a new notification (from the Service).

Also, see this answer: [Sending a notification from a service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207269/sending-a-notification-from-a-service-in-android)