# Setting Event in CalendarView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calendar

I am making an Exercise app that is designed so the user uses it once per day. Say the current date is July 9, 2016... How would I go about setting the first event on the current date(July 9) and the second event on July (11) and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access dates using the Calendar class. to get the current date/time you can just do the following

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

if you wanted to get a different day you can do something like

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 11);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to the Calendar to get events in the following way -

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
long today = Calendar.getTimeInMillis();      // July 9

calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
long day_after_tomorrow = Calendar.getTimeInMillis()      // July 11
```

But, automatically events cannot be set like that in Calendar. It can only be used to get the time and date. If you want some sort of periodic notifications, check out -

- Alarm Manager
- Notification Manager

These have to be used in combination with Services and Broadcast Receivers.
Check these out for reference: [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example), [Sending a notification from a service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207269/sending-a-notification-from-a-service-in-android)