# Updating info while application is closed

Tags: android, push-notification

I need to create an app which gets data from an array on the web and send a push notification when there is a change in the array's contents. The part with the array parsing is done, but how can I listen to it for changes that listening to be done while the app is closed. How can I do that?

Comment: you'll need to implement support for Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) - https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Android's Services. This may be what you are looking for. You should use a service to "listen" for changes in your array and then spawn a notification if there has been a change.

Here are some links to get you started!
[Android Services](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)
[Spawning Notifications from Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207269/sending-a-notification-from-a-service-in-android)

Happy Coding